# R incorporate for loop into pipe to calculate percentile rank across many cols

Tags: r, for-loop, pipe

```
dfW %>%
  group_by(Grade,year) %>%
  mutate(pctRank.x = rank(x)/length(x))
```

I use the above code to calculate percentile rank as grouped by grade and year.

Instead of just apply this to a col named as x, I have about 15 different cols (e.g., a, b ,c....etc). For each one of these col, I would like to get a new one to store the percentile rank as pctRank.a, pctRank.b etc... in dfW. Is there a way to incorporate a "for loop" to make this faster?

Thanks!

Comment: This is precisely what the function `across` is for. No need for a loop.

Comment: Thanks. I do have a follow-up question: some of the columns used for percentile rank calculation have missing values, but rank and length does not allow for rm.na=T. I also don't want to remove all rows before the calculation. Is it possible to remove na before calculating percentile rank for each col with the current structure?

Comment: You could use `ifelse` here - `ifelse(is.na(x), NA, rank(x)/sum(!is.na(x)))`. NA values are automatically ranked bottom, so the result for the non-NA values will be the same as if you had omitted the NAs, and the NAs will remain as NA